# Looking for a way to search multiple strings in a one liner for zipgrep

Tags: linux

I tried the below options to search multiple search patterns in a one-liner, but its not working for **zipgrep**.
I am trying to search for multiple search patterns in a zip file.

Tried:

```
zipgrep -s 'search_item1|search_item2|search_item3' test.zip

zipgrep -s '(search_item1|search_item2|search_item3)' test.zip

zipgrep '\(search_item1|search_item2|search_item3\)' test.zip
```

Comment: `zipgrep '\(search_item1\|search_item2\|search_item3\)'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be a bug. `zipgrep` is a shell script, you could open it directly and comment out the following two lines

`vim /usr/bin/zipgrep`

```
# Escape shell-special characters in "pat".
# pat=` echo "$pat" | \
# sed -e 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g' -e 's/|/\\\|/g' -e 's/&/\\\&/g' `
```

save and retry your command, it should work normally.

```
# zipgrep 'client|fmt' ./test.zip
https.go:   "fmt"
https.go:   client := &http.Client{}
https.go:   res, err := client.Do(req)
https.go:   fmt.Println(res, err)
```